# jquery.tap run the function without event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, switch-statement, location-href

```
function onHref(href){
    window.location.href = href;
}
```

When i run the code automatically get redirected to the last obj[key].link

```
switch ( obj[key].type ) {
        case 'href': //se href attribuisce link diretto alla pagina
            $(id).tap(onHref(obj[key].link));
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are invoking the function by adding `()` at the end of `onHref`.

One solution is to use a anonymous function as the event handler then call `onHref` inside it

```
$(id).tap(function () {
    onHref(obj[key].link)
});
```

Another option is to use Function.bind() to create a function reference like

```
$(id).tap(onHref.bind(undefined, obj[key].link));
```